# why my feature object can not use feature.getGeometry method?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, geojson

When I draw a geometry, I want to add the geometry label inside the bounds and site in the central of the bounds for geojson layer on google map.

```
map.data.addListener("addfeature", function(feature){

var g=feature.getGeometry();
console.log("test ok");
//var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
console.log(g.get());
return feature;
});
```

I add map.data with a listener addfeature according to google develop reference (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)

According to page(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.AddFeatureEvent), the function catch up addfeature listener with arguement should be feature object.

According to feature class page(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Feature), feature object should have method getGeometry().

but when I execute code above, I get an error from browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: feature.getGeometry is not a function
at He.<anonymous> (bakb.html:37)
at qe._.y.trigger (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:104)
at qe.<anonymous> (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:38)
at Object._.y.trigger (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:104)
at qe._.k.add (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:116)
at js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:69
at Object._.ab (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:35)
at Object._.re (js?sensor=true&callback=myMap:69)
at Ub (data.js:11)
at OF (util.js:136)
```

I invoke google map apis by：

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=myMap></script>
```

I think I use google map correctly.
But why feature.getGeometry method is not defined?
How to get Geometry from feature? and is that feature arguement in callback function is really feature object? if not how to get Geometry from arguement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addfeature` event listener returns a [`addFeatureEvent` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.AddFeatureEvent), which has a feature property, it isn't a feature itself.

> **Data.AddFeatureEvent object specification**
>   google.maps.Data.AddFeatureEvent object specification
>   The properties of a addfeature event.
>
> **Properties**
>   **feature** | Type:  Data.Feature
>   The feature that was added to the FeatureCollection.

```
map.data.addListener("addfeature", function(event) {
  var g = event.feature.getGeometry();
  console.log("test ok");
  //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // assuming all the features are points
  console.log(g.get());
});
```